# Latex Chronology Timeline Error?

Tags: latex, beamer

There seems to be an error within the Chronology package. Or maybe I am making an obvious error myself?

The following is a minimal example of the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{chronology}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\begin{chronology}*[5]{0}{35}{10cm}[\textwidth]
\event[0]{11}{$1$}
\event[11]{17}{$2$}
\end{chronology}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The second box, rather than being drawn as a box, is drawn is a point at the actual end point of the defined box. Changing the start from 11 to 10.99 resolves the issue. But that does not seem to be an apropriate solution? Does anyone have an idea?

Best, Jonas

Comment: Your MWE seems to compile and give the expected output (in my output the second box **is** 11 to 17)... do you read any error message or even a warning?